# How to dynamically change content with php ajax and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have created a page that populates a sidebar with links(categories) using a database table. The table contains names(names of the categories) and their ids.

```
     e.g 
           | **id** |**name**|
           |  1     |  Men   |
           |  2     |  Women |
```

**I need to do the following things:**

- When a link is clicked, a corresponding h1 tag changes it's value to
  the name of the link(the category name).
- A div tag, that displays product images below the h1 tag, also changes. I have created a table to hold product data. It contains the following data fields:

  ```
     **id**(id for the product)-INT[PRIMARY KEY]
     **category_id**(category id)-INT[FOREIGN KEY]
     **name**(product name)-VARCHAR
     **image**(image file name e.g "blu_dress.png" )

     e.g 
   | **id** |**categoty_id**|   **name**  |   **image**  |
   |  1     |       2       |black blouse |bla_blouse.png|
   |  2     |       2       |  blue dress | blu_dress.png|
   |  3     |       1       | brown shirt | bro_shirt.png|
   |  4     |       2       | blue blouse |blu_blouse.png|
  ```

**PHP CODE TO POPULATE SIDEBAR**

```
    <?php 
$dynamicList = "";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC");

$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount

if ($productCount > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $category_name = $row["name"];
             $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id='".$id."'");
             $dynamicList .= '

                <li id="categegoryLink">
                    <a href="category.php?ID="'$category_name.'"" onclick="">   
                         '.$category_name.'
                    </a>
                </li>

                ';
    }
} 
else 
{
    $dynamicList = "We have no categories listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

**AJAX CODE**

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","category.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**category.php**

```
<?php echo $category_id?>
```

**FURTHER INFO**
I can't post images since I don't have the reputation but I have an image that explains what I need further, if you need it.

Comment: I don't see any AJAX here, have you gone through a tutorial and run into a particular issue?

Comment: Yes but I had to abandon it completely .

Comment: Why? You should state the problem you had and the code you have/had. Coding something for you from scratch isn't something for this site. Here's a page that might be useful, https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/.

Comment: I appreciate the link and i'm not asking for a code from scrath. I was thinking of using this code <script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","category.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

Comment: I just need some way to return the value of the category_id when a link is clicked. I don't know if i'm asking too much.

Comment: I would use jquery, you won't have to worry about browser versions (within reason) and it has functions already written for this. When adding to your question please edit rather than adding code in the comments.

Comment: And also what is the content of `category.php` already?

Comment: currently it's empty. I want to parse the value of the category_id to it so I can use it for sql statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend using `jQuery` and for database use `PDO` instead of using `mysql`. The populated sidebar data is displayed as a list.

```
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data','root', 'passwd', $options);
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC"); // you can also use prepared statement.
 // displaying categories 
<ul id="category">
   <?php foreach ($sql as $category) : ?>
      <li data-id="<?php echo $category['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
 <div id="results"></div>
```

And in your `jQuery` check for the clicked list item

```
$("#category li").click(function() {
           var id = $(this).data('id');
          $.post('get.php',{category_id:id},function(data){
              $('#results').html(data);
          });
     });
```

the code for the `get.php` file

```
<?php
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data','root', 'passwd', $options);
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC"); // you can also use prepared statement.
 if(isset($_POST['category_id'])){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$category = $db-query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = $id");
}
 ?>
  <h1><?php    echo $category['name']; ?></h1>

    <!--display the results of the query here-->
```

Here when the user clicks any of the list items `jQuery` will get the value of the `data-id` attribute 0f which is the id of the category, post this value to `get.php` file  and select data from the database based on id of the category. And return results form the database. The returned data is appended to the div with id `results`.